# Como impedir que aconteça o erro de favicon?

Tags: html

Sempre que subo o servidor local aparece a mensagem de

```
Error 404! Favicon.ico is not found
```

Como tiro esse erro sem colocar nenhuma imagem no html.

obs: eu não escrevi que estava procurando Favincon no head.

Comment: Já limpou o cache? Testou em outro browser? Tem certeza que não tenho nenhum script injetando esse Favicon no documento? Já inspeciono a página pelo DevTools para ver se a tag do Favicon está no head?

Comment: Colocando um arquivo de imagem do formato "icone" na pasta raiz com o nome `favicon.ico`... esse erro ocorre porque o navegador MESMO SEM O <link> tentará carregar da raiz um possivel favicon.ico. cc @hugocsl

Comment: Ou remova a indicação do favicon.ico que pode estar em algum arquivo de manifesto ou em alguma tag do <head>

Comment: @LeandroAngelo é nativo dos navegadores como Chrome (chromium) e Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É natural acontecer isso nos navegadores, quando não tiver o `<link rel="icon" ...>`, o navegador tentará carregar da raiz um possível `favicon.ico`, ou seja, a tentativa de carregar um possível favicon é justamente para ajudar que as abas, janelas, histórico e favoritos sejam melhores identificados (visualmente) pelo usuário final.

Exemplo, criei um `index.html` vazio:

```
<html>
<body></body>
</html>
```

E iniciei um servidor local http e acessei esse HTML:

> [image: Firefox força carregar favicon.ico]

### Como evitar a mensagem 404 quando não tiver um favicon

Um meio de resolver é criando uma **imagem vazia** de 1px por 1px tipo ícone, ou png, ou gif na raiz do seu servidor (seja local ou remoto).

Ou então usar o `data URI scheme` **vazio** dessa forma em todas suas páginas HTML:

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:,">
```

---

O motivo do `favicon.ico` ser carregado a partir da raiz quando omitido no HTML provavelmente é devido a uma questão histórica, mais especificamente no *Internet Explorer 5.01*, *5.5* e *6* (no Netscape e Opera da época não lembro se tinham necessidades ou se quer tinha suporte), nessa época o bookmaker (favoritos) era muito usado e alguns sites não conseguiam carregar o ícone em bookmaker ou mesmo exibir na barra de endereço, então alguém fez o teste de colocar na raiz e apontar também com `<link rel="icon" ...` e funcionou, mas creio que isso foi um equivocou, pois me parece que o motivo de ficar na raiz era porque as pessoas confundiam o caminho relativo do ícone quando navegava em uma subpasta/suburl e sugeriram manter na raiz para evitar problemas.

O que me recordo muito bem é que no *Internet Explorer 6* os favicons nunca funcionaram corretamente, eles só funcionavam de verdade quando adicionado ao bookmarker e se me recordo não funcionavam em todas páginas, era algo bem meia-boca, diferente do IE7 em diante, que isso foi "corrigido".

Essa situação especifica do comportamento do favicon nas versões do Internet Explorer, 5.01, 5.5 e 6 não estão documentadas oficialmente, o funcionamento que expliquei foi após **DIVERSOS** testes que fiz na época que esses navegadores estavam em alta (especificamente o 6, mas sempre fazia alguns testes para garantir retrocompatibilidade).

Eu só contei toda essa história desses navegadores que há muito tempo ninguém usa mais para explicar o possível de navegadores modernos tentarem carregar automaticamente o favicon a partir da raiz do site, isso provavelmente se manteve devido a uma questão de retrocompatibilidade para que diversos sites não quebrassem, assim os navegadores forçam usar da raiz **quando omitido no HTML**, para facilitar a orientação do usuário pelas abas, independente da página que navegue.